# For creating static library, do i need to enrolled in 'iOS Developer Program'

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

To create a static library in iOS, do I need to buy *iOS Developer Program*. Currently, when I build the  project , I got an error:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.2'

I tried most of the solution like changing "Code Signing Identity" . But I am not enrolled in iOS Developer Program.

Comment: Developer account doesn't required to develop a static library,  if you want to run it on device you need generate the certificates in that case developer account required

Comment: When I build my project with iOS Device, it results into build fail. It creates the '.a' file in Products folder. But when I use this file in my local app, I got following error:-